# Inserting an image into excel file

Tags: excel, vbscript, activex, ole

How to insert an image into excel file in a below way??

```
Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = app.Workbooks.Add
wb.Worksheets(1).Activate
wb.Sheets(1).Cells(1,5).Value = 'code for inserting image
```

Comment: @DavidCandy I am not sure that i have figour out your comment, could your explain please

Comment: It will be cool to see vbs example